# What is memory space occupied for reference and object

Tags: c#

What happen at background(in case of memory) when I declare variable  and then create object for that variable . Is reference variable store anywhere and in which format and how this variable points to the memory on heap. Please clarify below doubts in the comments.

For example

```
ClassA instance;       // Where this variable store and how much memory occupies
instance=new ClassA(); //How instance variable points to memory
```

**EDIT**

What will effect on my program memory if my program contains so many unused variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *instance* variable is just a pointer at runtime, it points to the object allocated in the GC heap.  The variable can live anywhere, stack, CPU register, inside another object that's on the heap or in the loader heap if it is static.

The big deal about the garbage collector is that it is capable of finding this pointer during a garbage collection.  And can thus see that the object is still referenced and can adjust the pointer value when it compacts the heap.  That's fairly straight-forward when the reference is static on inside another object.  Harder when it is on the stack or a register, the jitter provides sufficient info to let the GC find it.

Answer (score 1):

The storage location of a local variable for the reference itself is platform dependent (jitters can choose where they want to store it.)  Typically it will be in memory on the call stack for the method defining the local or in a CPU register.  The size is also platform dependent, but is generally 4 bytes for 32-bit architecture and 8 bytes for 64-bit architecture.

The reference may or may not 'point' to the heap.  It's better to think of it as an opaque reference identifier which can be used for accessing the object.  The underlying pointer can change at runtime.

Regarding unused variables, the optimizing compiler will often eliminate any unused local variables entirely, so it has no impact at all on runtime performance.  Also, the type of overhead you're talking about for storing a reference is miniscule for modern platforms.

Answer (score 1):

A reference variable is stored inline. If it's a local variable, it's allocated on the stack, if it's a member of a class it's allocated as part of the object on the heap.

An instance of a class is always allocated on the heap.

A reference is just a pointer, but what's special is that the garbage collector is aware of the reference. So, a reference uses the amount of space that a pointer uses. In a 32 bit process it uses 4 bytes, in a 64 bit process it uses 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need answers about this then I would recommend you get your hands on "CLR via C#", it is a book about how the CLR functions and it includes lots of information about this.

To answer your question, there are many things that you need to think about to answer this question.

For instance you need to store the instructions for each method in the class.  When the class first loads this will effectively be a pointer to the .Net IL instructions.  When the method is first needed by the application, it will be JIT compiled to actual instructions for the processor and this will be stored in memory.

Then you have static storage for class fields that will be stored only once per class.

Each class in .Net that is instantiated requires storage for various reasons, but not limited to things like inheritance, garbage collection, layout.  Then you have storage for the various references that you may keep to the object which will itself take storage.

If memory is truly critical to what you are doing, then C# may not be the best choice for your application.  Otherwise, just enjoy the benefits in productivity you will gain from using .NET and accept that this ease of use comes with a price of memory usage and less performance (in some cases) from a C/C++ app.